# qt/qml quick item - scale without pixelation

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm trying to design a zoomable view in qt/qml where you can adjust the scaling of the rendered widgets similar like in a browser or `QtWebView`.
My first try was to use the scale attribute. Though scaling everything, an unwanted side effect is that the UI gets pixelated.

There exists the `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` environment variable. The rendered result is what I'm looking for but the scale factor cannot be changed anymore after creating the `QGuiApplication`. 
Additionally it scales everything on the gui, but maybe this issue could be solved if i found a way to manipulate `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` dynamically at runtime.
I assume that `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` overrides the `QScreen::devicePixelRatio` property, but i didn't found a way to manually set this property since it is readonly.

Is there a way to manipulate `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` at runtime or exists another way to implement such a zoomable view?

With kind regards,

Neconspictor

Comment: You have to make sure all elements are scalable and define a global variable for scale factor. Then you must multiply any size property with this scale factor variable. So font sizes, dimensions, line widths and so on will be scalable. Keep in mind that any bitmap image will be pixelated so you must use vector images or big images.

Comment: @ S.M.Mousavi : If this is the only solution I will use it. But his approach is very unflexible, as I would have to replace common types like Switch which are not scalable by default. Thanks anyway